# Noninverting-amplifier offset

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have this circuit. [image: My circuit]

The input for the INA is +- 5uV.

Can somebody tell why there is a giant offset at the noninverting amplifier. Especially if i connect two non-inverting amplifiers in series it results in an +4 v offset if meausere just before the rectifier. I've tried to place buffers before the amplifer, but it doesnt seem to fix it.

Comment: I would say it is because the whole circuit from R2 onwards is DC coupled and the Non-inverting stage has enormous gain. Any small DC offsets of the preceding amplifiers, or the non-inverting stage OpAmp, will be multiplied by that gain

Answer (score 2):

The TL08x series of opamps have a typical input voltage offset error on the order of 3 mV ([datasheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082.pdf)). This offset is indistinguishable from a real input, and it gets amplified the same way.

I assume you're talking about U1 in your diagram, which is configured for a gain of about 5000×. This means that the output error could be on the order of 15 V (!), so if you're measuring just a few volts, you're actually doing much better than "typical" in your setup.

Since you're already bandpassing your signal, you should include a low-frequency rolloff in your noninverting amplifier in order to minimize the effects of its input offset error. One common way to do that is to incorporate a "DC offset servo" (try googling that phrase) into the feedback of that stage.

Comment: Thank you :) Never heard about DC offset servo in my class but i think it sounds very smart!

Answer (score 2):

The TL081 is not the best part to use if your trying to gain up your signal. The voltage offset is in the mV range. Your 'new' gain stage has a gain of (1+(50k+49.2k)/20) = 4963. If you gain the Vos=3mV of the TL081 from the bandpass filter by 4963 you get 14.8V, and that is beyond the rails. I would expect this circuit to rail out, but you may have a different offset. The TL081 is a cheap part. They have op amps that have voltage offsets in the uV range but are more expensive. Placing buffers before the amplifier is going to make the problem worse because every amplifier has a voltage offset and it also adds noise. 
A few Ideas:
Did you know that you can add gain into your bandpass filter without having to gain the output?
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html
This may or may not work depending on your dynamic range (you don't want your signal to hit the rails)

Another idea would be to capacitively couple the new gain stage and get rid of the offset coming from the bandpass filter.

The whole idea of analog signal design is to 'do math' on the signal of interest to measure it. Generally you have a small signal that you want to gain up. Everytime you add a gain stage you add in voltage offsets, noise and distortion. Most of the time it's a good practice minimize the opamps in the design to reduce the cost and degradation of the signal.

Comment: Thank you :). I think i'll try to change the TL081 with OPA227, AC-couple the circuit, and then turn down the amp gain. i've heard that it could be a good idea to implementing "stabilizing resistors" before the instrumentation amplifer...do you think thats a good idea? (The purpose of the system is to collect muscle signals)